# How to pass parameter through Nav link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used `meta_search` gem.

`controllers/feed_entries_controller.rb` is

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:search])
    @feed_entries = @search.all
  end
end
```

and in `Models/feed_entry.rb` have `:is_to_read` attribute(boolean data type)

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :summary, :url, :published_at, :guid, :is_to_read
end
```

and my question is, How to make nav link + pass parameter with below condition from `views/feed_entries/index.html.erb`?

Condition: pass `is_to_read(attribute) = true` and so that I can fetch only `feed_entries` with `is_star = true.`

Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want your URL to be something like `/feed_entries?is_to_read=true` ?

If so do:

```
feed_entries_path(is_to_read: true)
```